# How to access and make a func inside an enum Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I am new to Programming, i have to make a func that is used for
search of an item, and if the item is found the recipe must be printed. Example:

```
enum Grocery  {
    case Wine
    case Pork
    case Onion
}
enum RecipePorkWithWine: String {
    case Wine = "2 Glasses"
    case Pork = "4 Pieces"
    case Onion= "2 pcs"
```

How to make a func that search in the recipe and if the item is found the recipe should be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define Grocery, Receipt

```
enum Grocery  {
  case wine(num: Int)
  case pork(num: Int)
  case onion(num: Int)

  func printRecipe() {
    switch self {
    case .wine(let num): print("\(num) Glasses")
    case .pork(let num): print("\(num) Pieces")
    case .onion(let num): print("\(num) pcs")
    }
  }
}

class Receipt {
  var grocerys: [Grocery] = []

  func add(grocery: Grocery) {
    grocerys.append(grocery)
  }

  func printRecipe() {
    grocerys.forEach { $0.printRecipe() }
  }
}
```

usecase

`Grocery.onion(num: 10).printRecipe()`

`Grocery.pork(num: 2).printRecipe()`

when using receipt model

```
let receipt = Receipt()
receipt.add(grocery: .onion(num: 2))
receipt.add(grocery: .pork(num: 4))
receipt.add(grocery: .wine(num: 2))
receipt.printRecipe()
```

output

```
2 pcs
4 Pieces
2 Glasses
```